# Does one have a profit in an Islamic banking system?

Tags: riba, finance, banking

Usually when you open an account in a bank they try to attract you with interest.
My question is how so called Islamic banks can -likewise- offer their customers, especially as riba (and interest is clearly considered as such) is haram.

My understanding of Islamic banks is that it seems to be like a co-partnership,
which may mean that one may gain wins if the business runs or get losses if it doesn't. Like it is the case with trading one may buy a product (or in case of manufacturing produce it) and sell it with a (higher) price in order to make some wins, but at the end one may either make the wins, or it ends up as a shelf warmer, or you can't establish your business well enough etc.
If this understanding is correct usually a win or profit is uncertain.

In other words my question is what is the profit for the customer when opening an account in an Islamic bank (or does one have a profit)?

(In [this article](https://www.alfikra.org/chapter_view_a.php?book_id=268&chapter_id=4) -only in Arabic- explain how Islamic banks get and use the money a Sudanese author actually say that the Faisal Islamic Bank [بنك فيصل الإسلامي](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A8%D9%86%D9%83_%D9%81%D9%8A%D8%B5%D9%84_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%8A_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1%D9%8A) is only avoiding -seemingly the term- riba by trickery and basically attacking all Islamic banking systems)

Comment: Google translation of that article gave pretty on point translation in my language.

Comment: @Tarik and what does it say or what have you concluded?

Comment: Well in the first part some terms are explained which were already been discussed on this forum (e.g. mudaraba (which is divided into two parties, one who provides money and who is accountable for most of the work), murabaha (a consensus of both the buyer and the seller concerning the price of a product that is being sold)). At the end Faisal Islamic bank gives a short analyzation of how it detects usury to avoid it.